# Korean characters reappear in text <input> after input value cleared and new KR characters typed

Tags: javascript, html, cjk

I am creating a project in which the user types Korean characters that are shown to them.

The first time a Korean character is typed, everything works as intended (*fig. 1*). But once the input field has been cleared at least once and another Korean character is typed into it, the previously entered character is unwantedly entered right before the newly typed character (*fig. 2*).

[*fig. 1* log after a Korean character (ㅐ) is typed after the page loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl0NF.png)

[*fig. 2* log after a Korean character (ㅏ) is entered later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9cp6.png)

In this example, "ㅐ" is displayed in the question field when the page loads. I enter ㅐ on my keyboard and *fig. 1* is displayed in the console (and "ㅐ" is shown in the answer field). After the input field is cleared, the question field displays "ㅏ". I enter ㅏ on my keyboard and *fig. 2* is displayed in the console and the answer field displays "ㅐㅏ".

This problem does not occur if Latin characters are typed or if Korean characters are pasted into the input. As far as I can tell the problem only arises if Korean characters are physically typed. I have found that by hitting backspace before typing a Korean character, the previous character is effectively deleted and doesn't get retyped before the newly typed Korean character.

I am using Windows 10 Home and Microsoft IME on Google Chrome & Microsoft Edge.

```js
const questionField = document.querySelector(".questionField");
const inputField = document.querySelector(".inputField");
let currentIndex;
let currentCorrectAnswer;
const characters = [
    "ㅏ",
    "ㅑ",
    "ㅐ"
]

inputField.focus();
generateQuestion();

inputField.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    if(inputField.value == currentCorrectAnswer){
        correct(e);
    } else if(inputField.value != ""){
        incorrect(e);
    }
})

function correct(e){
    console.log(inputField.value + " input & is correct." + " is composing: " + e.isComposing);
    questionField.innerHTML = "Correct"
    setTimeout(nextQuestion, 500);
}

function incorrect(e){
    console.log(inputField.value + " input & is incorrect, " + currentCorrectAnswer + " was the answer." + " is composing: " + e.isComposing);
    questionField.innerHTML = "Incorrect"
    setTimeout(nextQuestion, 500);
}

function nextQuestion(){
    generateQuestion();
    inputField.value = "";
}

function generateQuestion(){
    currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    questionField.innerHTML = characters[currentIndex];
    currentCorrectAnswer = characters[currentIndex];
}
```

```html
<h1 class="questionField">Key</h1>
<label for="inputField">Enter this key on your keyboard</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inputField" class="inputField" placeholder="Answer here">
```

Comment: Can't actually reproduce with the code you have given, https://jsfiddle.net/qrazh50e/ - this only ever logs the currently entered character to the console for me ...?

Comment: Please use the snippet tool `<>` here to post your code

Comment: What OS, IME, and browser are you using? These characters aren't combining on their own, but with consonants like ㅇ,ㅅ,etc. you could still have your IME stuck on composing mode. KeyboardEvents do expose an [`isComposing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/isComposing) attribute though in the `input` event composing is supposed to be over. But I've seen many bugs with various IMEs.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @CBroe I am able to reproduce the issue with both your jsfiddle link and my code snippet.

Comment: @Kaiido I am using Win 10 Home, Microsoft IME, and Chrome (I also tested with Edge and had the same problem).

Comment: @Kaiido with your info I was able to find a workaround. By using `inputField.blur();` followed by `inputField.focus();` in the nextQuestion function the duplicate characters are no longer input before the typed characters. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you add your specs inside the question that would make it a proper question for StackOverflow and may gather the last *reopen* vote that's missing. Then you'd be able to add your solution as a self-answer. Ps: I'm myself on macOS with *2-set Korean* IME and can also repro on Chrome only, so that'd be a Chrome bug. Feel free to open an issue at https://crbug.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blurring and re-focusing on the answer field once an answer is checked fixes the issue.

This can be done by editing the nextQuestion function like so:

```
function nextQuestion(){
    generateQuestion();
    inputField.blur();
    inputField.focus();
    inputField.value = "";
}
```